# Bibliography with Multiple Sections

Tags: biblatex

I will try to explain what I want: I would like my bibliography to be divided in 2 big categories: first, the Primary Sources (which will only contain a few items) and then the Secondary Sources. The Secondary Sources section will be divided in multiple subsections, based on themes. I would like for there not to be a page break between my "Primary Sources" section and my "Secondary Sources" section. I have tried a few solutions given here but they have not worked. How can I get them both to appear on the same page? Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=mla,showmedium=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inreference{University2010,
  title = {University, n.},
  booktitle = {{{OED Online}}},
  date = {2010},
  edition = {Third Edition},
  publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
  urldate = {2020-06-25},
  keywords = {dico,secondary}
}
@book{byattPossessionRomance2009,
  title = {Possession: A {{Romance}}},
  shorttitle = {Possession},
  author = {Byatt, A. S.},
  date = {2009},
  publisher = {{Vintage Classics}},
  location = {{London}},
  isbn = {978-0-09-950392-7},
  keywords = {primary},
  langid = {english},
  pagetotal = {511}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword=primary,title=Primary Sources]

\chapter*{Secondary Sources}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Secondary Sources}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,keyword=dico,title=Dictionary Entries]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try printing your bibliographies as sections. See `\bibbycategory` in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your document class `\chapter` and `\chapter*` start a new (double)page, so I'd not use `\chapter*` for the 'Secondary Sources' heading.

I'd probably go with the following. This uses three levels of bibliography headings.

1. One overall heading.
2. The Primary/Secondary heading.
3. The keyword headings.

Then

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=mla,showmedium=false]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{subsubbibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{University2010,
  title = {University, n.},
  booktitle = {{{OED Online}}},
  date = {2010},
  edition = {Third Edition},
  publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
  urldate = {2020-06-25},
  keywords = {dico,secondary}
}
@book{byattPossessionRomance2009,
  title = {Possession: A {{Romance}}},
  shorttitle = {Possession},
  author = {Byatt, A. S.},
  date = {2009},
  publisher = {{Vintage Classics}},
  location = {{London}},
  isbn = {978-0-09-950392-7},
  keywords = {primary},
  langid = {english},
  pagetotal = {511}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, keyword=primary,title=Primary Sources]
\printbibheading[heading=subbibintoc,title=Secondary Sources]
\printbibliography[heading=subsubbibintoc,keyword=dico,title=Dictionary Entries]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Three heading levels]

Comment: thank you, this is perfect!

Comment: Beautiful answer!